# Clicking a link in <a> tag using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

suppose the following is mentioned in the tag a:

```
<a href=www.google.com/url?url=www.xyz.com> www.xyz.com/1213sdsd/en-us </a>
```

The text between the  tagname is also a link. How do I select the same using driver object in selenium.

my code:

```
String link = "www.xyz.com";
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText(link));
link.click();
```

Comment: <a href=www.google.com/url?url=www.xyz.com/> www.xyz.com/1213sdsd/en-us <a>

Comment: what is the issue with this ? whats the error you getting

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector"

Comment: try using explicit wait, to make sure the element is present. also try this locator driver.findElement(By.css(a[href*="www.google.com"]))

Comment: I am trying to click the text www.xyz.com/1213sdsd/en-us using partial link but it ends up in an exception. Usual text is working fine, if i have something like <a href = "www.google.com"> Google </a>.and i use by.linkText("Google").click();
Not able to use the same logic for the link in the tag.

Comment: can u mention the explicit wait syntax and its usage

Comment: is the element visible in your page ?

Comment: you have the website link where i could try it out?

Comment: yes the link is visible and its a password reset link so i am not able to share. You can try with any password reset operation its will generate a password reset link with a key.

Comment: its working fine for me , see if the anchor is inside i frame or somethiong

Comment: What driver are you using? And which version?

Comment: Yes the anchor is inside the iframe
I am using Chromedriver version 80